# ¿Hay un término para designar a los periecos de los antípodas?

Tags: vocabulario-técnico, solicitud-de-término, geografía

Los [**antípodas**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2vUgk3N) son

> 1. adj. Dicho de una persona con respecto a otra: Que habita en un lugar del globo terrestre diametralmente opuesto al lugar en el que habita la otra.

En el caso de España, aproximadamente corresponde a Nueva Zelanda.

Por otro lado, los [**periecos**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ScNfJ34) son

> 1. adj. *Geogr*. p. us. Dicho de una persona con respecto de otra: Que habita en un punto del globo terrestre sobre el mismo paralelo que ella, pero sobre el meridiano opuesto.

En el caso de España, corresponde aproximadamente a Japón.

¿Hay un término para referirse a los "periecos de los antípodas"? (En el caso de España, correspondería al Atlántico Sur, al suroeste de Sudáfrica)

Answer (score 9):

> [**anteco, ca**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2mJ4pVe)
>
> Del lat. tardío *antoeci, -ōrum*, y este del gr. ἄντοικος *ántoikos* 'que vive al lado opuesto'.
>
> **1.** adj. *Geogr.* p. us. Dicho de una persona con respecto de otra: Que habita en un punto del globo terrestre sobre el mismo meridiano que ella y a igual distancia del ecuador, pero en el hemisferio opuesto. U. t. c. s.

Comment: Cuando leí la pregunta no me imaginé que si hubiera una respuesta. Excelente +1